# ElasticSearch don't work utils range for date

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch, and my query are not seeking  the information that I want.

```
{
    "query": 
    {
        "bool": 
        {
            "must": 
            [
                {
                    "range": 
                    {
                       "date": 
                       {
                           "gte": "2016-04-29 00:00:01",
                           "lte": "2016-04-29 23:59:59"
                       }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The results is everything the date possible, so, is like if the query don't exists.

```
POST /Test/date
{
     "date": "2016-04-28 13:43:14"
}
```

I various the day when I run, so I run also

```
POST /Test/date
{
     "date": "2016-04-29 13:43:14"
}
```

and

```
POST /Test/date
{
     "date": "2016-04-30 13:43:14"
}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: How are you sending your query? With GET or POST and which client are you using?

Comment: Can you show a document that matches but shouldn't match?

Comment: Id be curious to see the **exact and complete** command you use to run the query. And the mapping of the index.

Comment: Yeah, your `date` field is a `string` actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You need a custom date format, basically, otherwise ES creates a `string` field, not a `date` one as it doesn't recognize the format.

```
DELETE test

PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "date": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/date
{
  "date": "2016-04-28 13:43:14"
}
POST /test/date
{
  "date": "2016-04-29 13:43:14"
}
POST /test/date
{
  "date": "2016-04-30 13:43:14"
}

GET /test/date/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "2016-04-29 00:00:01",
              "lte": "2016-04-29 23:59:59"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the field is `date` type, how would ?

Comment: Please, provide the mapping of that index: `GET /test/date/_mapping`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is because your timestamp format is incorrect. Can you change from:

- 2016-04-29 00:00:01

To:

- 2016-04-29T00:00:01